# What causes materials like Vantablack to have their high optical absorption properties?

Tags: reflection, refraction, thermal-radiation, absorption, nanoscience

As per the title of this post. From reading, I understand that blackbody radiation is a factor I should consider here, with light being absorbed and converted to heat etc.

However, what I want to understand is just what causes Vantablack to behave like blackbodies? Materials like Vantablack is made up of CNT forests, but just what is it about CNT forests that lead to them having such high absorption? Is it something to do with the CNT band gaps?

I'd really appreciate it if somebody can explain this to me. Or, barring that, I'd really appreciate it if I can be directed to useful reading material.